# Is it actually possible for me to use py2app to package my program?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, python-3.7, py2app

So i'm not too experienced with coding in general, but i created this program that uses opencv and mediapipe, though both libraries seem to not work well with py2app. I say this because when i try and package my code into an app, it immediately fails on the 2nd line, which is where opencv is imported.

```
import cv2
```

where pycharm gives me the error:

```
 line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

which is very weird, as i have installed and uninstalled opencv multiple times, and installed opencv-python-headless as well, which seemed to make no difference.

even after following all of the debugging steps on all websites on the topic. I am extremely confused and frustrated with this problem, Any and all help is welcome. Thanks